# Why there is difference in arrayBuffer while getting inserted and getting back from mysql using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, blob

->While inserting image data(reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)) into mysql blob

```
Uint8Array(3594) [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 107, 172, 88, 84, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 143, 11, 252, 97, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 80, 76, 84, 69, 73, 191, 68, 73, 192, 67, 73, 192, 67, 73, 192, 67, 73, 192, 67, 74, 193, 68, 73, 192, 67, 72, 191, 67, 73, 192, 67, 74, 192, 67, …]
```

->while retrieving back from mysql blob image data is displaying as

```
Uint8Array(12325) [49, 51, 55, 44, 56, 48, 44, 55, 56, 44, 55, 49, 44, 49, 51, 44, 49, 48, 44, 50, 54, 44, 49, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 49, 51, 44, 55, 51, 44, 55, 50, 44, 54, 56, 44, 56, 50, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 49, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 49, 44, 48, 44, 56, 44, 51, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 49, 48, 55, 44, 49, 55, 50, 44, 56, 56, 44, 56, 52, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 48, 44, 49, 44, 49, 49, 53, 44, 56, 50, …]
```

Expected results should be same while inserting and retrieving back the Uint8Array()

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. "What could be the reason for the discrepancy" ?

Comment: I am using node mysql npm module.. except that i am not transforming the object anywhere

Comment: Is blob have any options in mysql while inserting or selecting back??